# Check Data Received Serial Port Android

Tags: data-transfer

I am receiving data through the serial port ( RS232 ) on my tablet sent from a micro. I want to know what is the best way to check if the data sent are equal to those received or check if any error occurred ?

```
private class ReadThread extends Thread {
        byte[] buf = new byte[512];

        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            while (!isInterrupted()) {
                int size;
                if (mInputStream == null)
                    return;
                size = serialPort.readBytes(buf);
                if (size > 0) { 
                    byte[] dest = new byte[size];
                    System.arraycopy(buf, 0, dest, 0, size);

                    byteLinkedList.offer(dest);
                    onDataReceived();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Google "Checksum" or "CRC" -- that should give you a good starting point.